# How to ORDER BY RAND() and set LIMIT randomly?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I want to extract random rows and I want the number of rows to variate every time I run
How can I make that happen?

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE sbb_data (
    scope_node VARCHAR(25), 
    site VARCHAR(20), 
    name VARCHAR(40),  
    is_deleted INT, 
    is_connected INT
);

SELECT name FROM sbb_data;
```

Output

```
SBB 1
SBB 2
SBB 3
SBB 4
SBB 5
SBB 6
SBB 7
SBB 8
SBB 9
SBB 10
SBB 11
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT name FROM sbb_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5;
```

I get something like this

```
SBB 8
SBB 9
SBB 2
SBB 10
SBB 4
```

But the number of rows output is always 5

I want it to variate between 0,5

Comment: You may need to do that from which ever language you are using to call the SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick 5 rows at random, then assign them a new random number; pick rows where the new random number is less than 0.5 (picking, on average, half the numbers, but possibly none, possibly all over them).

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM sbb_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5) rand5
 WHERE RAND() < 0.5
```

For example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c80a90b08e77e5e6448991d589f39df4

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is to insert a bit more randomness:

```
SELECT name
FROM sbb_data CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM sbb_data) x
WHERE RAND() < 5.0 / cnt
LIMIT 5;
```

This selects each row with a probability where "5" is the expected number -- however it could be more than or less than 5.  The `limit 5` limits this to 5.

As written, this would select 5 rows more often than other numbers.  You might want `4.0 / cnt` or `3.0 / cnt` for a more even distribution.

Also, on even modestly sized data, this is much faster than doing an `order by rand()`.

Comment: I tried the code but the problem is that I only get 5 rows or 0, nothing between

Comment: @Herker - Then you typed something wrong... Demo showing it working: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5eaaea3bb16283b96460b52af37c8035

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM 
( SELECT name,RAND() as rand FROM sbb_data order by RAND() ) as tab 
where tab.rand <0.5 LIMIT 5
```

insert a random value in the query and according to this value the number of rows will change `tab.rand <0.5` 
and `LIMIT 5` will limit the max number of row to 5 .

and changing the condition to `tab.rand <0.2`  will make geting number of rows <5 more probable

Comment: Code without explanation is useless.  Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: For a more 'normal' distribution, you should have the `LIMIT 5` inside the subquery.  With a large enough source set the current answer will very rarely select fewer than 5 rows.  See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=78e15451465931d251a133a190463f1e

Answer (score -1):

```
SET @nrRows = floor(rand()*6);

PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM sbb_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?';

EXECUTE STMT USING @nrRows;
```

Basically what you are asking is to limit based on a variable (`@nrRows`), which should take values between [0, 5].